# Get number of rows affected using 'Update' or 'Delete' query in SQLite-WinRT wrapper

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

How to get the number of rows affected in SQLite-WinRT wrapper for **Delete or Update** queries?  Here is the [blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8/) that describes the CRUD operations of SQLite-WinRT wrapper in Windows Runtime apps.

Some code snippet is:

```
var dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(dbPath);
db = new SQLiteWinRT.Database(dbFile);
await db.OpenAsync(SqliteOpenMode.OpenReadWrite);
await db.ExecuteStatementAsync("DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Name = 'abc'");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite-WinRT code base doesn't use `sqlite3_changes()` or `sqlite3_total_changes()` which are the functions offered by [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) to count affected records, so there seems to be no direct API to get that number.

However SQLite has the [changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function, so you could try to issue a  `SELECT CHANGES()` query after your `DELETE` and read the returned value (using `db.PrepareStatementAsync`, `stmt.StepAsync` and `stmt.GetIntAt`).

(Cant' test this approach at the moment).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. I will try this approach and let you know. One question: Lets say there are **DELETE** and **UPDATE** queries in a row and execute them one by one. Will  `SELECT CHANGES()` query returns the number of affected rows made by **UPDATE** query only?

Comment: *returns the number of rows modified, inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement*

Answer (score 1):

- You can count no of rows affected from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() as below

```cs
int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

- rowcount will be contain no of rows affected due to Insert or Update